# Is there a measurable bijection between two Euclidean spaces of different dimensions?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is there a measurable bijection between two Euclidean spaces of different dimensions? Specifically, is there  $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m\neq n$ such that $f$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: There is a (Borel) measurable bijection between any two complete separable metric spaces of the same cardinality. You can read about isomorophism theorems of measure theory.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Borel_space see “kuratowski theorem”